# psycopg, double and single quotes insert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I ran into problems, while trying to insert to database:

```
ur_psql.execute("""insert into smth(data, filedate, filedby)"""
                """ values('%s', NOW(), %s)""" % (data, userid))
```

where `data=""" "5.09,448,1418112000"; d="scan'208" """`(a string containing double and single quotes)
Any ideas how to insert such string to db ?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read about it at: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Simply do not use quotes in SQL and instead of `%` string Python operator use 2nd parameter of `execute()` which is data you want to pass to SQL query:

```
sql = "insert into smth (data, filedate, filedby) values (%s, NOW(), %s)"
ur_psql.execute(sql, (data, userid))
```

Comment: What should be the schema for inserting multiple values/records in same query? Unable to find a neat solution.

Comment: You can find example on the https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial page with `executemany()` and dictionary example.