# Treat single quotes in text file

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a plain text file separated by `~`

```
20-07-31-03:00~[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]
```

The script below receives the broken array as follows

```
with open('''/etc/files/plaintext.txt''') as f:
    resultCollect = f.read().splitlines() 
    resultSplit.append([line.split('~') for line in resultCollect])
    insert(resultSplit[0], table)

# resultSplit[0] --> ['20-07-31-03:00','[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]']

def insert(data, table):

    val = [tuple(line) for line in data]
    for i in range(len(val)):
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO {0} VALUES {1}""".format(table, tuple(val[i])))
```

However, due to the single quotation marks inside the string in `'DB_CONTENT'`, when trying to insert in the database the following error is generated

```
column "[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]" does not exist
```

Example of the generated insert

```
INSERT INTO tbl_details VALUES ('20-07-30-01:53', "[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]")
```

Reproducible example:

```
result = []
val = '''20-07-31-03:00~[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]'''
result.append([val.split('~')])

def insert(data, table):

  val = [tuple(line) for line in data]
  for i in range(len(val)):
    print("""INSERT INTO {0} VALUES {1}""".format(table, tuple(val[i])))

insert(result[0], 'tbl_name')
```

Any suggestion of solution?

Comment: What database library are you using? It looks like psycopg but you should clarify that.

Comment: I use `psycopg2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psycopg, double and single quotes insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965260/psycopg-double-and-single-quotes-insert)

Comment: I'm testing on the example of the question, but without success, can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never ever format SQL queries yourself, as [psycopg documentation says](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters):

> Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

The preferred way, as seen from docs examples is to let the library handle it.

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" # Note: no quotes
data = ("O'Reilly", )
cur.execute(SQL, data) # Note: no % operator
```

This should handle properly escaping your string with single quotes.

EDIT: Adding example with your code.
The proposed way above shouldn't be used to insert the table name (`INSERT INTO %s`), it should be used only on the data part (`VALUES (%s)`)

EDIT2: Didn't notice you want to insert two values `'20-07-30-01:53', "[*IF *VALUE *EQ 'DB_CONTENT'  *UNTIL]"`. I have edited the code, notice additional `%s` in query string. Also I can't really see what `val[i]` contains but it should be a sequence (tuple, list) of the two values you want to insert.

```
from psycopg2.sql import SQL, Identifier


SQL_QUERY_STRING = """INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s, %s)"""


def insert(data, table):
    val = [tuple(line) for line in data]
    for i in range(len(val)):
        curr.execute(
            SQL(SQL_QUERY_STRING).format(Identifier(table)),
            val[i],
            # second (data) argument has to be a sequene (tuple, list, ...)
            # of values to be inserted, even if it's just one value
        )
```

Comment: Can you help reproduce this in the example of the question?

Comment: Take in mind this is all nicely covered in https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: I test your example `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: I forgot you are trying to insert two variables, I have edited the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes shouldn't be used in the values section. Double quotes in Postgres are used to represent tables or columns. You should escape the single quotes using '' and prepare the insert statement. The insert statement should be written as INSERT INTO tbl_details VALUES ('20-07-30-01:53', '[*IF *VALUE *EQ ''DB_CONTENT''  *UNTIL]')

Comment: I understand that, the problem is how to handle it in python